# Conditional failing with two functions returning true

Tags: php, conditional-statements

So i have 2 functions that checks a users privilegues, and checks if the user can view the page.  But it will not work as intended, and i cant figure out why. It's probably really basic, but i dont see it.

Here in use:

```
if(!isAdmin() || !userCanAddCourses()) { 
    echo 'You dont have permissions to view this page';
    die;
    return false;
}
```

Here is the functions:

```
function userCanAddCourses(){
   $ugarr = getUserGroup($_SESSION['userid']);
    $dbtype = "mysql";
    $dbhost = DB_HOST;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;
    $dbuser = DB_USER;
    $dbpass = DB_PASS;
    $var = explode(',', $ugarr);
    foreach ($var as $ug){
        $doclibperm ='0';
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
        $sql = "SELECT * from roles where id=:ug";
        $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stm->execute(array(':ug' => $ug));
        $users = $stm->fetchAll();
        foreach ($users as $row) { 
            $addcourses = $row['addcourse'];
            if($addcourses=='1'){
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }   
}

function isAdmin() {
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $dbtype = "mysql";
    $dbhost = DB_HOST;
    $dbname = DB_NAME;
    $dbuser = DB_USER;
    $dbpass = DB_PASS;
    $network = getCurrentNetwork();
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    $sql = "SELECT * from users where network=:network and id=:userid";
    $stm = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array(':network' => $network, ':userid'=>$userid));
    $users = $stm->fetchAll();
    foreach ($users as $row) { 
        $moderator = $row['role'];
    }
    if($moderator >= '4'){
        return true;   
    }
}
```

In the scenario above, the user is an admin, but the userCanAadCourses function will not return true. 
Ive tried removing die and return false, and then it will show the page along with the "You dont have permission" echo.
Its like it runs the conditional twice instead of doing the two arguments as one conditional..

Code below will work, but i think my first approach should work.

```
if(userCanAddCourses()){
    $perm = 1;
} 
if(isAdmin()){
    $perm = 1;
}
if($perm != '1') { 
    echo 'You dont have permissions to view this page';
    die;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: `die` is a function. `if` is not a function to return value

Comment: return $addcourses and $moderator and call the functions with a print  and see what they both compare to when they `if($moderator >= '4'){`

Comment: In the current scenario, $addcourses returns 0 and $moderator returns 4